# Variable that double counts the observations

Tags: stata

I am trying to create a new variable such that it would count like
1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4 ..... meaning it would double count the observations.
My current code is like this

```
gen newid = _n
replace newid = newid[_n+1] if mod(newid2,2) == 0
```

but with this the result comes out as 1,1,3,3,5,5,7,7, ... where the increments are in 2's, i.e. I only get odd numbers. How should I modify this code?

Answer (score 2):

You might try dividing your ID variable by 2, and then use Stata's `ceil` function to force it up to the nearest integer.

```
clear 
set obs 50
gen newid = _n
gen newid2 = ceil(newid/2)
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you all for great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `int(x)` function.
This function returns the integer obtained by truncating x.

Thus, int(5.2) is 5.

If you want the following pattern

```
    1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9
```

the command is

```
    gen seq = int((_n-1)/2) +1
```

Comment: As `int` rounds down, you have to reverse that by adding 1. Tastes vary, but the `ceil()` solution in the answer of @ander2ed seems more direct to me.

Comment: Thank you for the idea Dinesh. Thank you

Comment: @NickCox - Both work well but for a large set `ceil()` might prove a better choice for the reason you mentioned.